# Why is D3 quadtree dropping nodes?

Tags: d3.js

I’m having issues with D3’s excellent quadtree appearing to drop nodes unpredictably.  I can understand that it might not return all nodes if they are closely overlapping, but it would be very useful to understand more about when this might happen so I can work around it.

But that assumes that I’m not misusing it.  If I run this with 10,000 points in data below, I get about a consistent ~29% drop in leaf nodes.  With only 200 I can get one drop.  This feels too high.

1. Am I doing something wrong with my quadtree implementation?
2. What could I do to work round this?

   var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree()
       .x(function(d){return d[0];})
       .y(function(d){return d[1];});

   var data = d3.range(10000)
       .map(function(d){
           return [
               Math.random(),
               Math.random()
           ];
       });

If I run this count of quadtree leaves, I get a number below data.length:

```
var qt = quadtree(data),
    count = 0;
qt.visit(function(p,x1,y1,x2,y2){
    if(p.leaf)count++;
});
```

But if I run this filter, it returns an empty array suggesting that they are all there:

```
data.filter(function(d){return qt.find([d.x,d.y]).id !== d.id;});
```

Where am I going wrong?!

Comment: Writing this out led to this observation: the first test uses p.leaf; the filter uses p.point. If I re-write visit using .point all are there. Am I misunderstanding what .leaf does?

Comment: Read the documentation. Leaves and points are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Leaf and point are not interchangeable. Points can exist on internal nodes.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom